# Kernel Programming meaning

Tags: kernel, computer-science

I am planning to get admitted to a university in US for my Masters. One of the pre requisite to get admit is Computer Organisation and Kernel Programming. What is it exactly? Does Kernel Programming means programming in Unix or Operating System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel  program stands for system side program .It acts as interface between applications and Hardware.
The Linux kernel is released under the GNU General Public License version 2 and Linux kernel was initially conceived and created in 1991 by Finnish computer science student **Linus Torvalds**. Linux rapidly accumulated developers and users who adapted code from other free software projects for use with the new operating system.

see below Linux kernel has a coding style guide:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle